# Help understanding and approaching the ODE $y + \sqrt{(y')^2 + 1} = k$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been trying to solve the following differential equation:
$$y + \sqrt{(y')^2 + 1} = k$$
where $ k $ is a constant. Despite my efforts, I haven't been able to find a closed-form solution for it. It seems to be a rather tricky equation due to its nonlinearity and the presence of the square root term. I've attempted various approaches, such as isolating the radical, squaring both sides, and reorganizing the equation:
$$
\sqrt{\left(y^{\prime}\right)^2+1}=k-y
$$
$$
\left(y^{\prime}\right)^2+1=(k-y)^2
$$
$$
\left(y^{\prime}\right)^2=k^2-2 k y+y^2-1
$$
$$
y^{\prime}=\pm \sqrt{k^2-2 k y+y^2-1}
$$
However, as you can see, I haven't made much progress towards finding an analytical solution.

At this point, I'm starting to wonder if this equation is solvable in closed form at all.

Are there any alternative methods or transformations that could potentially simplify the equation or lead to a solution?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: You already got a good answer, but you could also have noted that it's a separable ODE: $\int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{(\cdots)}} = \pm \int dx$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Substituting $u = k - y$, we get

$$ u = \sqrt{(u')^2 + 1},
\qquad\text{i.e.,}\qquad (u')^2 = u^2 - 1. $$

Now substitute $u = \cosh \phi$. Then by using the identities $\cosh^2 \phi - \sinh^2 \phi = 1$ and $(\cosh\phi)' = \sinh\phi$, we get

$$ \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi}{\mathrm{d}t} \sinh\phi \right)^2 = \sinh^2 \phi, \qquad\text{hence}\qquad \frac{\mathrm{d}\phi}{\mathrm{d}t} = \pm 1. $$

Let $\varepsilon \in \{ +1, -1\}$ denote the sign choice. Then $\phi = \epsilon t + c$ for some constant $c$, and so,

$$ y = k - \cosh(\epsilon t + c). $$

Comment: You type too fast for the old man ! Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, Thank you! I knew this problem would be very competitive, so I typed like a madman :)